# Can I use VS SSRS report builder tool to create paginated report from power bi instead of using power bi report builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

Can I use VS SSRS report builder tool to create paginated report from power bi instead of using power bi report builder
the power bi report builder doesn't support many features which is available for visual studio SSRS tool

no examples applicable

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed reports built in Visual Studio to Power BI service, but I did have to use Power BI Report Builder to do the actual deploy.